# textarea is read-only if a user deletes their bio. How do I prevent that

Tags: html, angular, ionic4

If a user deletes their bio on their profile page the field becomes read-only and you can't type in any text.  Kind of strange that it works that way.  How can I make this field editable regardless if their bio is `null` or `undefined`?  Right now, I have to manually insert text into the `firebase` field in order for the text area to be editable.

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-label>Enter bio</ion-label>
    <div *ngIf="bio">
      <textarea #myInput rows="2" maxLength="100" (keyup)="resize()" [(ngModel)]="bio" placeholder="Enter your bio"></textarea>
      <span>{{100 - bio.length}}</span>
    </div>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: Can you create a https://stackblitz.com/ for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your `*ngIf="bio"`. The way the template is written, you're only showing the textarea if the bio is `truthy`. This means that `0`, `''`, `undefined`, `null` and a few other values will cause the div to not show.

If you move the `*ngIf` from the containing div to the `<span>` that is displaying the length, it should fix your issue.

```html
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-label>Enter bio</ion-label>
    <div>
      <textarea #myInput rows="2" maxLength="100" (keyup)="resize()" [(ngModel)]="bio" placeholder="Enter your bio"></textarea>
      <span *ngIf="bio">{{100 - bio.length}}</span>
    </div>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```